# Track viewport offset to top

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of events that get fired depending on how far the user is on the page. Right now I'm using this

```
$(window).on({
    scroll: function() {
        trigger_scrolled();
    }
});
```

I have been fiddling with the idea of check every X amount of milliseconds but I don't know how they compare.

Right now the app but it is very memory consuming. Is there a faster way to do this? or any other alternative?

Comment: you could use jQuery `.scrollTop()` and fire the event on a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the amount a function is being called by using a throttle/debouncing mechanism. [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has one, [use a jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/), or [write your own](http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/)

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery scrollTop()

```
var allowed = true;
var timeoutID;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (!allowed) return;
    allowed = false;
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1000) {
        alert("Do stuff");
    }
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(){allowed = true}, 3000);
});
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K6aRw/1/

Edit: added a time-out to make it check less oft.

Comment: I didn't include it in the code above but my `trigger_scrolled()` it is already checking on the offset.

Comment: Ok, I've added a time-out, was that what you are lookign for?